# WPF toolbar disappearing on resize

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

On my main window I have a toolbar with a number of buttons. Once the parent window is resized down by dragging it so that the entire toolbar with all its buttons no longer fits in the width of the window, the whole toolbar disappears.

Is there a way I can make it so that as you resize it, when you get to the width of the toolbar the inner controls of the window stop resizing and stay displayed, just cut off where the window has resized to?

Code is

```
<Grid >
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToolBar Grid.Row="1" Height="50" Name="tbMainToolbar" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="900" >
    <ToolBar.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#DCEBFF" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="#99CCFF" Offset="0.75" />
            <GradientStop Color="#99CCFF" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ToolBar.Background>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Button Name="btnApproved" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Click="btnToolbar_Click" CommandParameter="APPROVED"
                Style="{StaticResource ToolbarButtonDisplay}" HelperClasses:ButtonProperties.Image="..\..\Resources\Images\APPROVEU.GIF" Content="Approve">
        </Button>
        ... and so forth for about 20 buttons
```

Comment: For one I would remove the MinWidth="900".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `DockPanel` in your toolbar, which contains all your buttons.

This means that the toolbar treats the dockpanel (and all its buttons) as one single 'item'.  When it doesn't fit, it hides the lot in the toolbar's overflow area.

If you get rid of the `DockPanel` altogether, and just put the buttons directly under the toolbar, the buttons will disappear one at a time when the window is resized (they will appear in the 'overflow area')

If you don't want them to go into the overflow area, you can use the `ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never"` attached property on each of your buttons.  This will result in the toolbar simply disappearing off the edge of the window as you describe in your question.

You could also just use this attached property on your dockpanel in the first place:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never">
```

Comment: `ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never"` is what I looked for! Thanks! _Now I know how to prevent a single toolbar button from disappearing when being partially shown (on small toolbar sizes)._